# Is there a way to add a dependency to a Maven POM from the command line?

Tags: xml, maven, command-line

Is there a command or Maven plugin I can use to add a dependency to a POM from the command line?

For example, I want to type something like:

```
mvn lazy:add-dependency -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=derp -Dversion=1.0
```

and have it modify the dependencies section of the POM in the current directory:

```
<dependencies>
    ... other dependencies ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>derp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

An external command to add the above XML would also work, but I'd prefer one that doesn't require me to write an XSL stylesheet.

Comment: Could you tell us in what context that would be useful.

Comment: I have a shell script which creates a new project from an in-house archetype.  As part of the script, I would like the new project to be added as a dependency on an existing aggregator project.

Comment: You could use `sed` to accompish this..

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you ever solved this, but I have done something similar in the past with xsltproc ( I Know you said not to use one, but I never found another way of doing it).

```
function merge_xml ()
{
TEMP_XML1="some-temp-file1.xml"
TEMP_XML2="some-temp-file2.xml"
cat > $TEMP_XML1
cp $1 $TEMP_XML2

echo "Merging XML stream from $1 into $2" >&2

xsltproc --stringparam with "$TEMP_XML1" merge.xslt "$TEMP_XML2" | tidy -xml -indent -quiet -wrap 500 -output $2
}
```

merge.xslt can be found here http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/merge/merge.xslt

Then to call the Bash function:

```
merge_xml $PROJECT_ROOT/content/pom.xml $PROJECT_ROOT/content/pom.xml << EOF 
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <classifier>jar</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
EOF
```

Comment: Small nit, the xsi:schemaLocation is not canonical in this snippet- Maven uses periods in the semver, whereas this uses underscores. "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" is the correct xsi:schemaLocation according to https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Comment: After fixing small nit above, I get a successful execution however instead of concatenating the two dependencies together dependencies from the merged in snippet overwrite dependencies from the pom. :( :( :( Huge waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an existing Plugin that does this, but it could be fairly straightforward to [implement your own Maven plugin leveraging Ant](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mcookbook/reference/ch04s04.html) and [XMLTask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/).

Answer (score 0):

Following Andrew's comment:

Example using sed:

```
sed 's/<dependencies>/<dependencies>\r\n<!--ghost-->\r\n<dependency>\r\n<groupId>org.ghost4j<\/groupId>\r\n<artifactId>ghost4j<\/artifactId>\r\n<version>0.5.0<\/version>\r\n<\/dependency>\r\n<!--ghost-->/g' pom.xml > pom2.xml
```

Replaces the dependencies tag with the dependencies tag followed by the new dependency (inserts the new dependency first in the list.

Creates a new file pom2.xml with the new dependency (this can be changed to overwrite the original file using: pom.xml > pom.xml

Comment: \r\n is the Windows newline.  \n is the Linux newline.  Edit as appropriate.